# BASH I would like this if-then-else behaviour explained

Tags: bash, scripting, freebsd

I have this short if-then-else script:

```
for INV in "$(ls np4178/*pdf)" ;\
do INVNUMB="$(pdfgrep -ho 'IN[0-9]{6,6}' $INV)" ; \
if [[ -z ${INVNUMB+x} ]]; \
then \
  echo "\n$INVNUMB" ; \
else \
  echo "wrong  \n$INVNUMB" ; \
fi ; \
done
```

Which produces this:

```
wrong  \nIN353886
IN353897
IN353905
IN353910
IN353902
IN353864
IN353875
IN353840
IN353862
IN353922
IN353739
IN353876
IN353920
```

However, if I make a change to the `else` statement I get this:

```
for INV in "$(ls np4178/*pdf)" ;\
   do INVNUMB="$(pdfgrep -ho 'IN[0-9]{6,6}' $INV)" ; \
   if [[ -z ${INVNUMB+x} ]]; \
   then \
     echo "\n$INVNUMB" ; \
   else \
     echo "\nIN000000" ; \
   fi ; \
done
```

Then I only get this:

```
\nIN000000
```

Why?  How can changing the text string in the `else` clause the entire behaviour and results of the script to change?

Why is the newline character `\n` printed as a literal in the `else` clause?

Comment: [Bash pitfall number one](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29).  See where it reads "You can't simply double-quote the substitution either".

Comment: None of the backslashes at the ends of lines are needed.

Comment: To begin with, I was using the wrong test.  -z should be -n

Comment: If the `xpg_echo` `shopt` option was set, `\n` would be special to `echo`; but, then, every `echo "wrong  \n$INVNUMB"` would print `wrong  ` +  a newline + the expansion of `$INVNUMB`. This is not what we see, telling us that `xpg_echo` is not set. Hence, (since `echo -e` is not used) `\n` is not special to `echo`, meaning that your first output snippet is produced by a _single_ `echo "wrong  \n$INVNUMB"`. Which seems consistent with the result you get when you change `"wrong  \n$INVNUMB"` into `"\nIN000000"`.

Answer (score 5):

There are some flaws in this code.

1. [Don't parse `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29).  And since you have the command substitution quoted every result is passed to `INV` as a single string.  Instead you can just loop over the glob results:

```
for inv in np4178/*pdf; do
```

2. You don't need any of the `;`'s or `\`'s in that code.  In fact the way they are written actually cancel each other out.  `;` is a newline separator and `\` is an escape character which when used at the end of a line escapes the new line.
3. echo (normally) doesn't interpret backslash escapes (`\n`), you could use `echo -e` but [printf is better than echo](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo)
4. As you have already discovered your test construct is checking if the variable **is** null when you apparently want to check if it **is not** null
5. There is absolutely no reason to do `${INVNUMB+x}`.

Here is what the code you want may look like:

```
for inv in np4178/*pdf; do
    invnumb="$(pdfgrep -ho 'IN[0-9]{6,6}' "$inv")"
    if [[ -n "$invnumb" ]]; then
        printf '\n%s\n' "$invnumb"
    else
        printf '\n%s\n' "IN000000"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Why do you even store the output of `pdfgrep` in a variable?? `if ! pdfgrep ... "$inv"; then echo IN000000; fi`.  This is assuming `pdfgrep` is sane about its exit-status.

Comment: I've never used pdfgrep, but it's possible that this is just a pared down example of OPs code and the `invnumb` variable will be used for something else

Comment: I'm just assuming it works like `grep`.

Comment: @Kusalananda: it appears that it does https://pdfgrep.org/doc.html

Answer (score -1):

Thank you for all the help.  It was very useful.  The example I gave was not the complete script, obviously.  And I did not comprehend the significance of enclosing env variables with `""`, so lesson learned.  And it was an early attempt at understanding the problem on my part so I was somewhat confused about what exactly I was trying to accomplish.

I posted this as an answer to get the code formatting right. What follows is, more or less, what I ended up with:

```
for INV in $(ls -1 $SRCDIR/HP3000-INV*pdf)
# search files for IN###### and return only first occurrence of match
do INVNUMB="$(pdfgrep -h -o -m 1 'IN[0-9]{6,6}' $INV)"
  if [[ -n ${INVNUMB} ]]; \
    then
      # prepend the invoice number to the file name
      # and move renamed file to xfr directory
      mv -f $INV $(dirname $INV)"/"$TODAY"/"$INVNUMB"-"$(basename $INV)
  fi
done
```

Comment: `for INV in "$SRCDIR"/HP3000-INV*pdf`

Comment: "I did not comprehend the significance of enclosing env variables with `""`".  You still have a number of unquoted variable expansions.